# if (in_array(<title>, $SomeArray)) return true

Tags: php, arrays, variables, filter, categories

I have problem that it cant detect every word in string. similar to filter or tag or category or sort of..

```
$title = "What iS YouR NAME?";

$english = Array( 'Name', 'Vacation' );

if(in_array(strtolower($title),$english)){
    $language = 'english';
} else if(in_array(strtolower($title),$france)){
    $language = 'france';
} else if(in_array(strtolower($title),$spanish)){
    $language = 'spanish';
} else if(in_array(strtolower($title),$chinese)){
    $language = 'chinese';
} else if(in_array(strtolower($title),$japanese)){
    $language = 'japanese';
} else {
    $language = null;
}
```

output is null.. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real problem here... the string in `$title` isn't in any of the arrays you are testing with, even in lower case.

Try testing every word in each language tab against the string instead.

```
$english = Array( 'Name', 'Vacation' );
$languages = array('english'=>$english,
                   'france'=>$france,
                   'spanish'=>$spanish,
                   'chinese'=>$chinese,
                   'japenese'=>$japenese);

while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = $line['title'];
    //$lower_title = strtolower($title); stristr() instead.

    $language_found = false;

    foreach($languages as $language_name=>$language) {
        idx = 0;
        while(($language_found === false) && idx < count($language)) {
            $word = $language[$idx];
            if(stristr($title, $word) !== false) {
                $language_found = $language_name;
            }
            $idx++;
        }
    }

    // got language name or false...
}
```

You could also breaking the string using `explode` of course and testing each word in the created array for each language.

Comment: it works but it gave error: `Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in /***.php on line 47`

Comment: you are right, I had to use `strstr();` instead, i will edit that.

Comment: maybe the interpreter doesn't like `if(strstr($lower_title, $word)`, I'll will edit again with `if(strstr($lower_title, $word))` ;-)

Comment: I suppose you had a fatal... I think strstr is more appropriate for that job since values returned by strpos can be of many different types.

Comment: i tried remove "break;" keep going until end row of mySQL... then that gave me same error said "Empty delimiter"

Comment: ok a short look at the doc gives me `stristr` and I think this will be my last edit

Comment: anyway, thanks.. i will find foreach skip to next of mysql_fetch_array($result) without use break;

Comment: @Vince let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1472/discussion-between-user453089-and-vince)

Comment: i found the problem.. thanks it works now! it was one empty in array.

Comment: nice, iwas quite sure of this on the end

Answer (score 2):

The output is `null` because the string `"what is your name?"` is not in any of the language arrays. Note that you should not write language names in code.

Instead, a dictionary or array of languages (in the form of dictionaries or objects) allows future extension and separates data from control logic.

Answer (score 1):

There are several logic issues:

The first problem is that you are trying to see if a multi-word string is in an array of single words. That will always fail to find a match. You would need to break up `$title` with [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and loop over the words.

ie) `$title_words = explode(' ', strtolower($title));`

```
foreach($title_words as $word){
  //check language
  //now you can use in_array and expect some matches
}
```

However that presents a second issue.What if a word is in multiple languages?

A third issue is in your sample, you have converted your search string to lowercase, but your array of matches has all words with an upper case first letter.
ie)
`$english = Array( 'Name', 'Vacation' );` should be
`$english = array( 'name', 'vacation' );`

if you expect matches

Comment: i ask if its possible to use explode with white space in `$title`?

Comment: will try test it now.. give me less than 5 mins.

Comment: @user453089 yes the first argument of explode is the delimiter which is set to break strings at whitespaces

Comment: i tried it with alot of $title.. one of them $title is work then others is not...